# How and where to generate a CSRF token for to make requests to a Django app through a REST API?

Tags: django, django-csrf

I have a Django view `login` that allows me to get a session for a user using POST data from an Android app. It works because I set the `@csrf_exempt` decorator, but I'll need the CSRF token for subsequent requests.

How can I get the CSRF token? Should it be generated on my Android app or on the Django app? Then how do I add it to my requests?

```
from django.contrib import auth
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser


class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """
    An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.
    """
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
            content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
            kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
            super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)


@csrf_exempt
def login(request, *args, **kwargs):

    # Login
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                    auth.login(request, user)
                    return JSONResponse({'success': 1, 'user_id': user.id})
            return JSONResponse({'success': 0, 'msg': 'User is not active'})
    return JSONResponse({'success': 0, 'msg': 'Wrong username and/or password'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the decorator `from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie` to my function to make it returns a CSRF token.

Answer (score 0):

Django documentation speaks on this here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

An alternative is to use a framework like http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication

Comment: I cannot see where they talk about my issue. Should it be created in the Android app? And in that case how is it done? Or in the Django app? And in that case how is it done, and how to make the first request with no CSRF token?

Comment: You should look into using that REST Framework and using TokenAuthentication like: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#tokenauthentication That way the user can pass their username/password to your server and get a token they can use on all requests to authenticate.

Comment: Say I'm using my login view. How can I generate a CSRF token on the Android side?

Comment: If you chose to use Django-rest-framework as answered by @stormlifter you need to make a login/password authentication on android. if the auth is validated then Django will return a http header with the Token that you will use.

Comment: The csrf token is not returned with my login function.